# How to transverse yaml file using variable in a function?

Tags: python, yaml

I am completely new to python and trying to write a script for work. Here is a sample snippet:

config.yml:

```
company1:
    threshold: 3
    alert:
        alert1: 0
        alert2: 0
company2:
    threshold: 6
    alert:
        alert1: 1
        alert2: 1
```

My Python script:

```
import yaml
from box import Box

with open("config.yml", 'r') as open_file:
    try:
        cfg = Box(yaml.safe_load(open_file))
    except yaml.YAMLError as err:
        print(err)

def myDef(foo):
    t = cfg.foo.threshold
    a1 = cfg.foo.alert.alert1
    
    return t, a1
    
v = myDef("company1")
print(v[0])
#desired result: 3

x = myDef("company2")
print(x[1])
#desired result: 1
```

Currently, I get an error:
`BoxKeyError: "'Box' object has no attribute 'foo'"`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please show the complete error message. (Also see [mcve]).

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the tip. I am updating now.

Comment: What is `Box` defined as?

Comment: @GoodDeeds My guess is it's the [Box Python library](https://github.com/cdgriffith/Box), which seems to be a wrapper around dictionaries. I'm not sure how a new Python coder wound up using it. If there's a tutorial recommending it to newbies, then it's not a great tutorial

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I see, thanks.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I am not completely sure. ```Box``` is the wrapper around ```cfg``` so that I wouldn't have to use brackets and apostrophes. However, as @SilvioMayolo notes, I will steer clear of ```Box``` for the time being since I'm a newbie.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Its my mistake. Here is the article. I should have known better when I saw "advanced" in the title :-) [Data Science in Production — Advanced Python Best Practices](https://medium.com/bcggamma/data-science-python-best-practices-fdb16fdedf82)

Comment: Frankly, "Box up your config" is horrible advice even to an expert Python coder. If you're doing data science, you should be making a class that understands the data, not hiding the lack of understanding using a library that also doesn't understand it. That article doesn't look terribly beneficial to me. There are a few common sense things in there but I disagree with lots of it

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I can’t upvote yet but again wanted you to know I appreciated the continued advice. There is so much advice and so many types of tutorials that it’s hard to know where to start.

Comment: There's a lot, absolutely. And mastery only comes with years of experience. It's a long road but it's worth it. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    t = cfg.foo.threshold
```

This is not referring to the local variable `foo`. It's trying to get the literal `"foo"` value from your dictionary. You probably want

```
    t = cfg[foo].threshold
```

I might also recommend *not* using the Box library at first. It looks like it does some fun interpreter magic to make your dictionaries more Javascript-like, and if you're just learning Python you're going to get confused and run into more situations like this where the Box solution is not the Pythonic one, and you'll be learning incorrect idioms.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. The codes works perfectly now. Additionally, I really appreciate the tip about using ```Box```. I will steer clear.